# Extract Value of CSV Column to Add Attribute

Tags: regex, csv, apache-nifi, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm working with some CSVs in NiFi and my pipeline is producing some duplicates. As a result, I'd like to use the `DetectDuplicate` processor, but in order to do this I need to have some attribute that it can compare against to detect duplication. I have an ExtractText processor, and I'd like to use regex to get the value in the `SHA1_BASE16` column.

I tried the following regex string (suggested by a friend, I don't totally understand it) on the CSV below but highlighted the incorrect fields and some extraneous stuff. How can I get it to capture *only* the `SHA1_BASE16` value?

**RegEx**

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*)\S*
```

**CSV**

```
"USER_JID","CREATED_AT","UPLOAD_TIME","SHA1_BASE32","SHA1_BASE16","HASH_SOURCE","MESSAGE_TYPE","IPV4"
"dreynolds","1932/04/01 20:23:35 UTC","2016/12/28 20:23:11 UTC","72F20077A79A0D4D90F4C0669FB6EA4BC5953293","FB1D928B83DEBCD2B2E53DF4C8D4C2AF99EB81E0","HOLLYWOOD","TWITTER","123.123.123.123"
```

**Actual Output**

```
Match 1
Full match  0-291   "USER_JID","CREATED_AT","UPLOAD_TIME","SHA1_BASE32","SHA1_BASE16","HASH_SOURCE","MESSAGE_TYPE","IPV4...
Group 1.    66-79   "HASH_SOURCE"
Group 2.    209-251 "FB1D928B83DEBCD2B2E53DF4C8D4C2AF99EB81E0"
Group 3.    274-291 "123.123.123.123"
```

**Expected Output**

```
Match 1
Full match  0-291   "USER_JID","CREATED_AT","UPLOAD_TIME","SHA1_BASE32","SHA1_BASE16","HASH_SOURCE","MESSAGE_TYPE","IPV4...
Group 1.    209-251 "FB1D928B83DEBCD2B2E53DF4C8D4C2AF99EB81E0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that we would be having two 40 chars strings here, which we would be using the first one as a left boundary, and apply this simple expression:

```
.+"[A-Z0-9]{40}",("[A-Z0-9]{40}").+
```

where our desired output is in this capturing group:

```
("[A-Z0-9]{40}")
```

which we can use `$1`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jXAe8T/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+"[A-Z0-9]{40}",("[A-Z0-9]{40}").+/gm;
const str = `"dreynolds","1932/04/01 20:23:35 UTC","2016/12/28 20:23:11 UTC","72F20077A79A0D4D90F4C0669FB6EA4BC5953293","FB1D928B83DEBCD2B2E53DF4C8D4C2AF99EB81E0","HOLLYWOOD","TWITTER","123.123.123.123"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use PartitionRecord to split the records into flow files where each record has the same value for the partition field (in this case `SHA1_BASE16`). It will also set an attribute on the flow file for the partition value, which you can then use in DetectDuplicate.

For high cardinality fields (ones that won't have many duplicates), you may see a performance hit since there could be a single row in each outgoing flow file, so for a large number of rows, you'll get a large number of flow files. Having said that, rather than DetectDuplicate downstream you could instead RouteOnAttribute where `record.count` > 1. That removes the need for a DistributedMapCache.

There is also a [contribution to add a DetectDuplicateRecord processor](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6047) which I think is what you'd really want here. That contribution is under review and I hope makes it into the next release of NiFi.

Comment: I think that contribution is exactly what I'm looking for! I ended up not going down this path, but I will keep this in mind in the future if I need to do this. And fingers crossed DetectDuplicateRecord ends up in the next release!